# Can an undirected graph cycle have only two vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

I've always seen cycles in graphs described as containing three or more vertices.  I had a question posed to me today that I now pose to you: Is it valid to consider a pair of vertices connected by a single edge in an undirected graph to be a cycle?

More concretely, given the following undirected graph:

```
a---b
 \ /
  c
  |
  d
```

Obviously, (c, b, a, c) is a cycle.  Is (c, d, c)?  Why or why not?

Comment: The edges in a cycle must be distinct,  whatever its length. $cabac $ isn't a cycle either.

Comment: Oh, of course. Thank you!